# redirecting user from gmail to flask app using html button

Tags: python-3.x, flask, redirect, gmail

so i am sending my users some `confirmation mail's` using `flask mail`. i want to **redirect** my users when a `html button` is clicked. but when i click the button, gmail is giving me this error: `The page you were on is trying to send you to an invalid URL (http:///index).` What is wrong here ??

**Flask Code**

```
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return "worked"
```

**Gmail Template (just the button part)**

```
    <!-- custom button -->
    <div style="margin-top:70px;text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" name="button"
            style="border:1px solid black;text-align: center;margin-right: 50px;background-color:white;color:black;padding: 14px 28px;font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;border-color: #17C671;color: #17C671;border-radius:30px;">Accept</button>
        <button style="border:1px solid black; background-color:white;color:black;padding: 14px 28px;font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;border-color: #E03A3A;color: #E03A3A;border-radius:30px;">Decline</button>
        <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">
            <button type="button" name="button">Home</button>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the value of `"{{ url_for('home') }}"`? It's trying to call: http:///index

Comment: yes i am trying to call ```http:///index```

Comment: It's an incorrect URL. If it's on local host, it should have http://localhost:{your-port}/home

Comment: @Saurabh that worked for me. thanks (: